# Image not filling the entire div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div. Inside it, I have an image. The dimension of the image is 540*420. I want the image to completely fill the container div, which is not happening. On the left and right of the image are whitespaces(denoted by pink colour in the image) which I want to remove. Screenshot of my image is:-

[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="background-color: pink; height: 270px; position: relative; background-size: cover;">
    <img src="images/about.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; object-fit: contain;" />
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 19%; left: 13%; width: 80%;">
        <p style="font-size: 1.4em; color: #fff; margin: 0; line-height: 1.7em; font-weight: 300; text-transform: uppercase;">
            apple pay runs afoul of mcx, a group with a rival product.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help.

Comment: Change image's `max-width:100%;` to `width:100%;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using classes `col-md-6` and `col-sm-6`. And these classes contain *15px* right and left padding rules:

```
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
```

Use `width: 100%`, `height: 100%` and `object-fit: cover` for the `img` tag, just override `padding` rules by adding `padding: 0` in the styles of `div`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="background-color: pink; height: 270px; position: relative; background-size: cover; padding: 0;">
    <img src="https://www.imgonline.com.ua/examples/bee-on-daisy.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" />
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 19%; left: 13%; width: 80%;">
        <p style="font-size: 1.4em; color: #fff; margin: 0; line-height: 1.7em; font-weight: 300; text-transform: uppercase;">
            apple pay runs afoul of mcx, a group with a rival product.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your first answer was not working but the second answer is working very well. Thanks for the prompt help.